# MonoTouch Create UIImage with rounded corners

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, rounded-corners

In mono touch how to create a rounded cornered image. I need to convert my UIImage view to a rounded cornered UIImage. Do anyone have a reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got an answer

```
UIImageView temp =myimageview;
                RectangleF rect = new RectangleF (temp.Frame.X, temp.Frame.Y, temp.Frame.Width, temp.Frame.Height);
                temp.Image = UIImage.FromFile("images/imagename.png");
                temp.Layer.CornerRadius = temp.Frame.Width/2;
                temp.ClipsToBounds = true;
                temp.ResizableSnapshotView (rect, true, new UIEdgeInsets (0, 50,0, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

add this in your

```
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.jpg"];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, NO, 1.0);
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:imageView.bounds 
                                cornerRadius:10.0] addClip];
    [image drawInRect:imageView.bounds];
    imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Hi Sport. Thank you for your solution. But i need a mono touch related solution. This code converting to mono touch is not working for me